# create nested dictionary in python dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have these two lists:

```py
top_levels = ["a", "b", "c"]
sub_levels = ["d", "e", "f"]
```

How do I create:

```py
nested_dict = {
   "a": {"d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0},
   "b": {"d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0},
   "c": {"d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension:

```py
>>> top_levels = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> sub_levels = ["d", "e", "f"]
>>> {t: {s: 0 for s in sub_levels} for t in top_levels}
{'a': {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0}, 'b': {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0}, 'c': {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It creates three references to the same dictionary. Try modifying one of the dictionaries: `d['a']['d']=10` - and see when happens to the other two. The list/dict comprehension solution is correct.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: Now I'm sitting here thinking "wtf is the point of `fromkeys()`?" I never actually use it but it was the first thing I thought of trying when I read the OP. Now I'm actually wondering, what is its use-case?

Comment: @blorgon: It's dramatically faster for the cases where it can be used. Among other things, back before `set` existed, and now, when `dict` can be used to make a `set`-like thing that maintains insertion order, it's a quick drop in replacement for the `set` constructor. And it's perfectly safe whenever the values aren't used, or are immutable types like `int`. In your code, you could safely do `{t: dict.fromkeys(sub_levels, 0) for t in top_levels}`, you just can't use it for the outer `dict` due to aliasing.

Comment: Right, that was actually the first iteration of my solution in REPL, but at that point it seems silly to not just resort back to a pure comprehension version. I'd be curious about the performance for larger sequences but am too lazy to do any testing.

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you:

```py
def func(top_levels, sub_levels):
    sub_level_dict = {}
    for sub in sub_levels:
        sub_level_dict[sub] = 0

    nested_dict = {}
    for top in top_levels:
        nested_dict[top] = sub_level_dict

    return nested_dict
```